# In material ui using makeStyles, is it possible to write a css rule that applies only if the element has both classes?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I know that I can do this in CSS.

```
.makeStyles-mainNavWrapper-67.sticky{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

I want to know if I can do this in Material-UI so that I do not have to have two separate stylesheets so to speak (one for the MaterialUI ReactApp and one that is linked in the HTML tag.

```
const Header = (props) => {
  const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    mainNav: {
      zIndex: '3',
      color: 'white',
      textAlign: 'right',
      marginRight: '10%'
    },
    mainNavWrapper: {
      paddingTop: '2%',
      background: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.8)'
    },
    mainNavWrapper.sticky: {
       I know this does not work. Is it possible?
    },
```

I tried to just string together two classes in MaterialUI and I get errors.

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer. I had to import the react-jss package and follow their documentation. I can now use the jssNested syntax and access nested elements and write rules that only apply if there are two classes attached to the element.

here it is:

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
// Import React-JSS
import injectSheet from 'react-jss'

// Create your Styles. Remember, since React-JSS uses the default preset,
// most plugins are available without further configuration needed.
const styles = {
  mainNav: {
    zIndex: '3',
    color: 'white',
    textAlign: 'right',
    marginRight: '10%',
    '& ul': {
      zIndex: '2',
      textAlign: 'right',
      listStyleType: 'none',
      margin: '0px',
    }
  },
  li: {
    '& a': {
      color: 'white'
    }
  },
  mainNavWrapper: {
    paddingTop: '2%',
    background: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.8)',
    width: '100%',
    opacity: '1',
    transition: 'width 2s ease',
    padding: '10px',
    '&.sticky': {
      // jss-nested applies this to a child span
      fontWeight: 'bold' // jss-camel-case turns this into 'font-weight'
    },
    '&.scrolling': {
      opacity: '0',
      position: 'absolute',
      transition: 'opacity 1s ease'
    }
  },
  myLabel: {
    fontStyle: 'italic'
  }
}

// Define the component using these styles and pass it the 'classes' prop.
// Use this to assign scoped class names.
const Button = ({ classes, children }) => (
  <div className={classes.mainNavWrapper}>

    <nav className={classes.mainNav}>
      <ul className={classes.ul}>
        <li className={classes.li} ><a href="#" >home</a></li>
        <li className={classes.li}><a href="#">about us</a></li>
        <li className={classes.li}><a href="#">packages</a></li>
        <li className={classes.li}><a href="#">reviews</a></li>
        <li className={classes.li}><a href="#" className={classes.current}>contact us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
)

// Finally, inject the stylesheet into the component.
const Test = injectSheet(styles)(Button)

export default Test;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I may have found it (extensive rubberducking)

https://github.com/cssinjs/jss-nested

```
const styles = {
  container: {
    padding: 20,
    '&:hover': {
      background: 'blue'
    },
    // Add a global .clear class to the container.
    '&.clear': {
      clear: 'both'
    },
    // Reference a global .button scoped to the container.
    '& .button': {
      background: 'red'
    },
    // Use multiple container refs in one selector
    '&.selected, &.active': {
      border: '1px solid red'
    }
  }
}
```

complies to:

```
.container-3775999496 {
  padding: 20px;
}
.container-3775999496:hover {
  background: blue;
}
.container-3775999496.clear {
  clear: both;
}
.container-3775999496 .button {
  background: red;
}
.container-3775999496.selected, .container-3775999496.active {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Some of my other code is broken so it will take some time to verify this.

Comment: The only issue with this is that it does not explain well how to use the plugin. Anyone know how to set this up?

Comment: Nice! The ampersand with the space and then .[classname] to access a nested class was tripping me up!

Answer (score 1):

I left the other answer because it shows how to solve this issue using react-jss. This you can do the same thing with makeStyles in MaterialUI. I must have had syntax error somewhere which was causing none of my css rules to go into effect.

Here's the makeStyles way, there's also some breakpoint code here to boot:

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const Header = () => {

  const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
      padding: theme.spacing(1),
      [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
        backgroundColor: 'red',
      },
      [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
        backgroundColor: 'blue',
      },
      [theme.breakpoints.up('lg')]: {
        backgroundColor: 'green',
      },
    },
    mainNav: {
      zIndex: '3',
      color: 'white',
      textAlign: 'right',
      marginRight: '10%',
      '& ul': {
        zIndex: '2',
        textAlign: 'right',
        listStyleType: 'none',
        margin: '0px',
      }
    },
    li: {
      display: 'inline-block',
      marginLeft: '3%',
      '& a': {
        color: 'white',
        textDecoration: 'none',
        marginRight: '10px',
        padding: '10px',
        '&:hover': {
          background: '#3498db'
        }
      }
    },
    mainNavWrapper: {
      background: 'rgba(0,0,0,1)',
      width: '100%',
      opacity: '1',
      transition: 'width 2s ease',
      padding: '10px',
      position: 'fixed',
      zIndex: 1,
      '&.sticky': {
        position: 'fixed',
        top: '0px',
        opacity: '1',
        transition: 'opacity 2s ease',
        padding: '10px',
        zIndex: 1
      },
      '&.scrolling': {
        opacity: '0',
        position: 'fixed',
        transition: 'opacity 30ms ease'
      }
    },
...
in the functional component's return ():
 <div className={classes.root}>

      <div className={classes.mainNavWrapper}>

        <nav className={classes.mainNav}>
          <ul className={classes.ul}>
            <li className={classes.li}><a href="#" >home</a></li>
            <li className={classes.li}><a href="#">about us</a></li>
            <li className={classes.li}><a href="#">packages</a></li>
            <li className={classes.li}><a href="#">reviews</a></li>
            <li className={classes.li}><a href="#" className={classes.current}>contact us</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

      </div>
</div>
```